# Get HashMap entry or add it if there isn't one

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I want to do something like this:

```rust
fn some_fn() {
    let mut my_map = HashMap::from([
        (1, "1.0".to_string()),
        (2, "2.0".to_string()),
    ]);

    let key = 3;

    let res = match my_map.get(&key) {
        Some(child) => child,
        None => {
            let value = "3.0".to_string();
            my_map.insert(key, value);
            &value // HERE IT FAILS
        }
    };

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

but it compiles with errors:

```
error[E0597]: `value` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:16:13
   |
16 |             &value // HERE IT FAILS
   |             ^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |             borrow later used here
17 |         }
   |         - `value` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `value`
  --> src/lib.rs:16:13
   |
14 |             let value = "3.0".to_string();
   |                 ----- move occurs because `value` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
15 |             my_map.insert(key, value);
   |                                ----- value moved here
16 |             &value // HERE IT FAILS
   |             ^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59e530de5d287484c1dfba53b7395535)</sup>

How can I fix it elegantly? Make a copy of string seems to me non-optimal.

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that you're inserting the `value` string then trying to return a reference to it, despite it already being moved into the HashMap. What you **really** want is to insert the value then get a reference to the **inserted** value, which *could* look something like this:

```rust
let res = match my_map.get(&key) {
    Some(child) => child,
    None => {
        let value = "3.0".to_string();
        my_map.insert(key, value);
        my_map.get(&key).unwrap() // unwrap is guaranteed to work
    }
};
```

**BUT DON'T DO THIS.** It's ugly and slow, as it has to look up the key in the map twice. Rust has a convenient [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) type that lets you get an entry of a `HashMap` then perform operations on that:

```rust
// or_insert returns the value if it exists, otherwise it inserts a default and returns it
let res = my_map.entry(key).or_insert("3.0".to_string());
```

Alternatively, if the operation to generate the default value is expensive, you can use `or_insert_with` to pass a closure:

```rust
// this won't call "3.0".to_string() unless it needs to
let res = my_map.entry(key).or_insert_with(|| "3.0".to_string());
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like balance the accepted answer a bit: There are two issues in using

```
let res = my_map.entry(key).or_insert_with(|| "3.0".to_string());
```

The first issue is that `entry(key)` requires ownership of `key` for all lookups to be able to potentially create the new entry. In `let res = match my_map.get(&key) { ... }` only the actual insertion requires ownership. But `HashMap` is typically used when you look up orders of magnitude more often than you insert. So if you have e.g. long String keys that need to be allocated on the heap and copied around, the `get()` variant might be cheaper.

The second issue is that `or_insert_with()` permits no error handling. If you need to construct something for insertion into the `HashMap` that might return an error during construction, you can only change the `HashMap` to store `Result` values -- which is a bit awkward. In this case, `get()` will likely be simpler.

As an example, I am keeping a `HashMap` for mapping file names to open files, so likely both issues 1 and 2 apply.